# How to sort data-points in X ayis of a plot

Tags: python, sorting, matplotlib

[image]I'm trying to plot data from a dictionary. Each dictionary value will produce one line in the plot (values are lists of lists)

These lines have different number of points, and for this reason X ayis points are not sorted properly.

For example in the image above, point "3802814" is found for a line after points 3848766 & 3872755, and is plotted to the right side (not sorted properly as I want).
I understand that dictionaries cannot be sorted as such, to overcome this.

The code is:

```py
# Dictionary: timing_of[clk_name]= {"clk1": [[Xlabel1, N1, M1, L1], [Xlabel2, N2, M2, L2]...]}
for clk_name, clk_data in timing_of.items(): 
   # Plot Xlabels with N-values in Y axis
   plt.plot([col[0] for col in clk_data] , [col[1] for col in clk_data], label=clk_name) 

plt.gca().legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1 , 0.8), prop={'size': 7}) 
plt.show()
```

How can I either:
1. sort the X ayis before showing the plot
2. alternatively, sort the data before I plot them?

Comment: Please share actual input data. One possible reason for the x-axis not being sorted is that X values are strings instead of numbers (but without data it's impossible to tell).

Comment: This has nothing to do with dictionary sorting. It's because your points are strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest :

This had nothing to do with dictionary sorting. It was because my points were strings instead of numbers.

A simple casting to integer with int() solved it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy

```
import numpy as np
# Dictionary: timing_of[clk_name]= {"clk1": [[Xlabel1, N1, M1, L1], [Xlabel2, N2, M2, L2]...]}
# Dictionary: timing_of[clk_name]= {"clk1": [[Xlabel1, N1, M1, L1], [Xlabel2, N2, M2, L2]...]}
X_all = np.array([])
Y_all = np.array([])
for clk_name, clk_data in timing_of.items(): 
   X = np.array([col[0] for col in clk_data])
   Y = np.array([col[1] for col in clk_data])
   argsort = np.argsort(X)
   X = X[argsort]
   Y = Y[argsort]
   # search the indexes to append in the right place
   appendIndex  = np.searchsorted(X_all, X)
   X_all = np.insert(X_all , appendIndex, X)
   Y_all = np.insert(Y_all , appendIndex, Y)

plt.plot(X_all , Y_all)
```

Comment: I edited the solution, didn't test it though, I wish that helps

Comment: There is a type error with np.searchsorted, "cannot cast array data from dtype float64 to dtype <U32"

Comment: I don't know the structure of the data you are using, but I think if you force the data into a particular type that could work , `X_all = np.array([], dtype = np.float), Y_all = np.array([], dtype = np.float)` and then when creating X  and Y you could do `X = np.array([col[0] for col in clk_data]).astype(np.foat)` ans the same with Y

Comment: Thanks for the try, still this gives only one line plotted, and the "clk_name" info is ignored. I'll probably try to change the data structure to something that can be sorted in the first place.